# Clarifications needed on why certain arguments related to quantum maps dubbed as false

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, open-quantum-systems

As I was learning more about the evolution of open quantum systems, I came across [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33078/what-is-a-completely-positive-map-physically). Reading through the answers, I found [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375960105005748) by A. Shaji and E.C.G. Sudarshan.

The mathematical arguments provided in the article clearly imply that NCP (not completely positive) maps are just as good as CP (completely positive) maps for certain cases. An example is provided to illustrate that if the reduced dynamics of a system is not positive on some of its states, then that must be treated as an indication of entanglement between the system and its environment. To restore physical consistency, a compatibility domain is defined in which the action of the NCP map is positive on all the states within the domain. The line of reasoning questions the justification we put forward in restricting the reduced dynamics of open quantum systems to exclusively CP maps.

[Ron Maimon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4864/ron-maimon) comments this at the end of that answer (and the comment had a few upvotes too):

> Shaji and Sudarshan's paper is completely bogus.

Of course, NCP maps fail to preserve linearity as stated in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409817/physical-meaning-of-ncp-not-completely-positive-maps) and hence might not be of much use. Still, I fail to understand why is the paper entirely bogus. Could someone please clarify what important points am I missing related to the article?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because general review of papers is not on topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Introduction

With some assumptions and approximations, the time-evolution of an open quantum system can often be adequately modelled using **completely positive** (CP) maps, as reviewed in [3], [4], and [5], specifically using CP trace-preserving (CPTP) maps, which are also called **quantum channels**. (The definitions are given below.) For example, page 1 in [6] says:

> > In *quantum information theory*, noisy evolution is usually modelled by completely positive, trace preserving (CPT) maps.

One reason for focusing on CP maps is convenience: the general properties of CP maps have been thoroughly characterized mathematically. For example, any such map may be expressed using a **Kraus representation**. Page 1 in reference [7] mentions a more fundamental reason for the widespread use of CP maps:

> Given a factorized initial system-environment state and a unitary interaction between system and environment the reduced time evolution has to be CP...

But what if the initial system-environment state is *not* factorized? Should we then use a non-CP map to represent the system's dynamics, as suggested in [1]? We need to be careful here, because "not using a CP map" is different than "using a map that is non-CP." The issue is with using a *map* at all, whether or not it is CP. This answer explains why.

---

## Positive maps and the partial trace

Consider a Hilbert space ${\cal H}={\cal H}_S\otimes{\cal H}_R$ where $S$ is the system of interest and $R$ is a "reservoir" (aka environment). An operator $A$ on ${\cal H}$ is called **positive** if it satisfies
$$
\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle\geq 0
\tag{1}
$$
for all $|\psi\rangle\in{\cal H}$. A better name might be "non-negative," but I'll stick with traditional language and call it "positive" even though the right-hand side of (1) can be zero. Let $\rho$ be any density matrix (unit-trace positive operator) on ${\cal H}$, and let $U$ be any unitary transformation on ${\cal H}$, so that 
$$
U\rho U^\dagger
\tag{2}
$$ 
is another density matrix on ${\cal H}$. Let 
$$
\rho_S\equiv\text{Trace}_R(\rho)
\tag{3}
$$ 
denote the partial trace of $\rho$ over the reservoir $R$, so that $\rho_S$ is the reduced density matrix of the system $S$. The reduced density matrix $\rho_S$ is a positive operator on ${\cal H}_S$, which can be proven using the definition of the partial trace, using the fact that $\rho$ is a positive operator on ${\cal H}$. Here's the proof: for any $|\phi\rangle\in{\cal H}_S$, we have
\begin{align}
\langle\phi|\rho_S|\phi\rangle
  &= \langle\phi|\text{Trace}_R(\rho)|\phi\rangle \\
  &= \sum_k\langle\phi, k|\rho|\phi,k\rangle
\tag{4}
\end{align}
with 
$$
|\phi,k\rangle \equiv |\phi\rangle\otimes |k\rangle
\tag{5}
$$
and where the vectors $|k\rangle$ are an orthonormal basis for ${\cal H}_R$. Now observe that if $\rho$ is positive, then every term in the sum (4) is non-negative. This completes the proof that $\rho_S$ is positive in ${\cal H}_S$. The proof that $\rho_S$ has unit trace (if $\rho$ does) also follows easily from (4).

---

## Illustration

If we start with a valid density matrix $\rho$ on the combined system, then the partial trace yields a valid reduced density matrix $\rho_S$. To illustrate what can go wrong if we're not careful, consider this two-qubit example from section 3 of [1]:
$$
\rho=\frac{1}{4}\left(
\left[\matrix{1&0\cr 0&1}\right]
\otimes
\left[\matrix{1&0\cr 0&1}\right]
+
\left[\matrix{0&1\cr 1&0}\right]
\otimes
\left[\matrix{0&0\cr 0&-2}\right]
\right),
\tag{6}
$$
which the paper [1] writes as ${\cal R}=\frac{1}{4}(1-\sigma_1+\sigma_1\tau_3)$ where $\sigma_k$ and $\tau_k$ are Pauli matrices acting on the first and second qubits in a two-qubit Hilbert space. The corresponding reduced matrix $\rho_S$ of the first qubit is *not* positive. There is no contradiction here, because the example (6) is *not* a valid density matrix on the two-qubit Hilbert space. In particular, it is not postive, because
$$
\langle\psi|\rho|\psi\rangle < 0
\hskip2cm
\text{when }
|\psi\rangle\propto \left[\matrix{1\cr 1}\right]
\otimes
\left[\matrix{0\cr 1}\right].
\tag{7}
$$
To get a valid reduced density matrix $\rho_S$, we should start with a valid density matrix $\rho$ on the combined system.

---

## The dynamics of an open quantum system

The focus here is on properties of the "map"
$$
\rho_S\to \rho_S'
\tag{8}
$$
defined by
$$
\rho_S\equiv\text{Trace}_R(\rho)
\hskip2cm
\rho_S'\equiv\text{Trace}_R(U\rho U^\dagger)
\tag{9}
$$
for some fixed unitary matrix $U$ on ${\cal H}$. If $\rho$ is a valid density matrix, then so are $\rho_S$ and $\rho_S'$. This was proven above.

Now, suppose that the total state $\rho$ has the form
$$
\rho=\rho_S\otimes\rho_R.
\tag{10}
$$
If the factor $\rho_R$ is *fixed*, then equations (8)-(9) define a legitimate map from density matrices on ${\cal H}_S$ to density matrices on ${\cal H}_S$. In fact, in this case, the map (8) is **completely positive** (theorem 3.3 in [2]). This means that the associated map 
$$
\rho_S\otimes I\to\rho_S'\otimes I
$$ 
is positive whenver $I$ is the identity operator on some auxiliary Hilbert space ${\cal H}_W$ (sometimes called the **witness**).

On the other hand, if $\rho$ does not have the form (10), then it is not clear to me that the form of $\rho$ can be naturally restricted in a way that makes (8) a map in the strict sense. If $\rho$ is not restricted, then for a generic $U$, we may be able to vary $\rho$ in a way that varies $\rho_S'$ without varying $\rho_S$. This is an obstacle to thinking of (8) as a map, in the strict sense of the word "map." To illustrate this, consider a two-qubit Hilbert space ${\cal H}$ with $\rho=\rho_S\otimes\rho_R$ and let $U$ be the unitary transformation that swaps the two factors. Then $\rho_S'=\rho_R$ even though $\rho_S$ is independent of $\rho_R$. So if $\rho_R$ is not fixed, then (8) is not a map at all, much less a CP map.

The transformation (8) still represents partial information about a unitary map on the larger Hilbert space (equations (9)); but (8) itself is not a map in the strict sense, because the same input $\rho_S$ can yield different outputs $\rho_S'$, even if the unitary transformation $U$ is fixed. The key points here are that if the dynamics is defined by taking a partial trace over part of a closed system with an unspecified initial state, then:

- In general, the dynamics of an open quantum system is not given by a CP map.
- In cases where we can't use a CP map, we typically can't use a *map* at all, CP or otherwise.

Again, though, with some assumptions and approximations, the time-evolution of $\rho_S$ can often be adequately modelled using CP maps, as reviewed in [3], [4], and [5]. We just need to remember the limitations of those assumptions and approximations.

---

## References

[1] Shaji and Sudarshan (2005), "Who's afraid of not completely positive maps?" *Physics Letters A* **341:** 48-54, https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~gsudama/pub/2005_003.pdf

[2] Wood (2009), "Non-Completely Positive Maps: Properties and Applications," https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3199

[3] Chruściński and Pascazio (2007), "A Brief History of the GKLS Equation," https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05993

[4] Breuer (2008), "Non-Markovian quantum dynamics and the method of correlated projection superoperators," https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.0172

[5] Hall et al (2010), "Canonical form of master equations and characterization of non-Markovianity," https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.0845

[6] Cubitt et al (2010), "The Complexity of Relating Quantum Channels to Master Equations," https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c0db/f877764741361f2dcde2f440d5b29c5cea3e.pdf

[7] Vacchini (2016), "Generalized master equations leading to completely positive dynamics," https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01150

Comment: +1. I read the whole answer. I am willing to award bounty, but it got expired, and was closed as off-topic before I could see your answer. I'm not sure as to how to award now.

Comment: @expikx Don't worry about it. I learned some things in the process of coming up with this answer, and that was my real motive. So I got exactly what I wanted, namely a little more insight than I had before.

Comment: I am sorry though. If I am allowed to reopen the question, I will definitely award you that well-deserved bounty.

Comment: In hindsight, I understand why general review of papers is considered off-topic. To respect that guidance, I edited my answer to suppress the paper-critiquing flavor. Now it focuses on the question "Should the dynamics of an open quantum system be described by a non-CP map?" To do this, I re-arranged things and made several adjustments to the wording, but the technical content is still the same. (Just wanted to let you know the reason for the edit.)

Comment: When you say that "'separable' means $\rho = \rho_S \otimes \rho_R$", shouldn't that be "product state"? I thought that a separable state was a convex combination of product states.

Comment: @tparker You are right -- I was mis-using the word "separable." I edited the answer to fix this.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly By the way, fantastic answer, +1. Does (9) alone impose any restriction at all on the allowable transformations (8)? Or is it the case that for any valid states $\rho_S$ and $\rho_S'$ at all, you can cook up a corresponding transformation (8) with an appropriate choice of $\rho$ and $U$ (that will depend on the desired final state $\rho_S'$)? What if either $U$ or $\rho$ is fixed and you're only free to choose the other?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly ah, I see the argument that is made. I don't buy it though. When you go from a unitary (or other map) to the map that describes its action restricted to a subset of inputs and outputs, you always have to consider the "neglected inputs" as part of the specification of the map. If you don't know those, that means that your map should be described as a convex combination of the possible maps. In your example, that would be a combination of maps of the form $\Phi_\sigma(\rho)=\sigma$ for all $\sigma$ which gives (I think) the map $\rho\mapsto I/N$.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly what I don't understand how might be possible is the existence of a physical operation that cannot be described as a CP map. My qualm would thus be with your first concluding statement. I see that something similar seems to be stated in the papers you linked though, so I suspect this boils down to semantics, and what exactly should be considered as a "physical map". As far as I understand, if we are talking about "physical operations" as "*devices that can conceivably be built and somehow operate on states*", then every possible such device should be describable as a CP map.

Comment: The Wikipedia page on "quantum operation" says that "in principle, the density matrix of a quantum system can undergo completely arbitrary time evolution," but there's no citation so I'm not sure exactly what is being claimed there.

Comment: @glS Is the appropriate definition of "physical operations" really "devices that can conceivably be built and somehow operate on states", as you claim? That only seems to include (human-) *controlled* operations like those used for quantum communication or computation. But if you're just trying to phenomenologically model some messy and uncontrolled open system where you truly have no idea what's going on in the environment, then I don't see why we should assume that the system and the environment should start out unentangled (and even classically uncorrelated).

Comment: @ Chiral: sure!  @tparker I don't think there is a formalised widely accepted definition, but I also don't see any realistic scenario in which non-CPTP aren't sufficient to model a system. As long as you believe that the underlying dynamics is modelled by the Schroedinger equation, then any corresponding evolution can be modelled via a CPTP map. If you go beyond that, then sure, anything can happen, but that's not QM anymore, nor there is any evidence for that

Comment: @tparker I don't think whether the initial state is entangled or not matters in this regard. What matters is that if the map is not CP, then it would in principle be possible to take that same set of interactions (or whatever the map is built out of), apply them to a different state, and produce a nonsensical result. I don't see how such a thing could model a physical situation.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly So on second thought, it clearly is possible for (9) with no further restrictions to lead to a completely arbitrary transformation of the form (8): you gave an explicit example in your answer, with the "swapping" unitary, where you take an arbitrary $\rho_S$ to an arbitrary $\rho_S'$!

Comment: @glS What? I don't understand what you're saying at all. The entire point of Chiral Anomaly's answer is that Schrodinger evolution does *not* necessarily lead to a CPTP map, or indeed to *any* deterministic map, unless we assume that the initial state is a tensor product of the system and a *fixed* environment state. You certainly don't have to "go beyond QM" to get system evolution that isn't given by a CPTP map.