# Lindblad Master equation for an entangled system and environment?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

I am currently trying to work out the math involving the time derivative of the density operator of an entangled system. (The total density operator, $\rho_T,$ is pure, but the 2 reduced density operators, $\rho_f,$ are entangled.) I've been looking into using the Lindblad equation to model the time-dependence of either reduced $\rho_f$ but the derivations of the Lindblad equation that I have found so far (such as at https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04478) depend upon making assumptions along the line of separability of $\rho_T$ into $\rho_1 \rho_2$ either initially or throughout the entire evolution. As such, my question comes in 2 parts:

1. Is there a derivation of the Lindblad equation that does not make either of these assumptions (and, if so, where might I find a good version of it)?
2. If not, then is there a derivation of the Lindblad equation that does not assume separability along the entire evolution (and, if so, where can I find a rigorous, but physically motivated, version of said derivation)?

Comment: I don't remember for sure, but some of the references I cited in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410204) might address the case of an entangled initial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 9 of Breuer and Petruccione's book on Open Quantum Systems has a couple of nice microscopic derivations of the Lindblad equation (derived in various ways from the von Neumann equation for the total density matrix).

One of the subsections in that Chapter is about the Nakajima-Zwanzig equation, which gives an exact solution for the reduced density matrix (which can then be perturbed in the system-environment coupling). The derivation assumes that the initial state is uncorrelated $\rho(0) = \rho_\mathrm{sys} \otimes \rho_\mathrm{env}$, but does not assume this for the entire evolution (which is partially what you seek). The Lindblad equation can be recovered as a limit of these equations.